# Algorithm to return list of indices of a run length

Tags: python

I'm working on a function that will accept a list of integers and a "run length" as arguments. The goal is to return a list of the indices of the first element of each "run" that increments or decrements by 1 for the given run length

e.g.

`values=[1,2,3,5,5,9,8,9,10,11]`, `run_length=3` would return `[0,6,7]`

Where I've gotten so far, and can't quite get what I'm messing up:

```
def solution(values, run_length):
    count = 0
    previous_int = 99
    marker = 0
    accumulator = 0
    locations = []

    for i in values:
        if i == (previous_int + 1):
            accumulator += 1

            if accumulator == (run_length - 1):
                locations.append(marker)
                accumulator -= 1
                marker += 1

        else:
            marker = count
            accumulator = 0
        count += 1
        previous_int = i
    return(locations)

values=[1,2,3,5,10,9,8,9,10,11,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
run_length=3
result = solution(values, run_length)
print(result)
```

Will work for some test cases but not all, like the above will only return `[0,6,7]` when there are clearly more.

Comment: Can you explain how you got [0,6,7] as solution for sample input?

Comment: @Prats `1,2,3` starting at 0, `8, 9, 10` starting at 6, `9, 10, 11` starting at 7.

Comment: @Prats as ddejohn mentioned above. The goal is to store the first indices of each run in the new list and print it out, so since the first run's first integer is `1` in the list, it coincides with `0`, and it follows this pattern wherever a run of 3 +/- 1 exists. If there's a 7,6,5, it would track that too for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a second pass for handling a decreasing sequence, then merge the two lists together. This code is somewhat long for my liking, but including all the code is necessary because some of the changes are subtle.

```py
def solution(values, run_length):
    increasing_locations = []
    decreasing_locations = []
    
    for differential, location_storage in [(1, increasing_locations), (-1, decreasing_locations)]:
        count = 0
        previous_int = 99
        marker = 0
        accumulator = 0
        for i in values:
            if i == (previous_int + differential):
                accumulator += 1

                if accumulator == (run_length - 1):
                    location_storage.append(marker)
                    accumulator -= 1
                    marker += 1
            else:
                marker = count
                accumulator = 0
            count += 1
            previous_int = i

    merged_result = []
    increase_location_index = 0
    decrease_location_index = 0

    while len(merged_result) < len(increasing_locations) + len(decreasing_locations):
        if decrease_location_index == len(decreasing_locations):
            merged_result.append(increasing_locations[increase_location_index])
            increase_location_index += 1
        elif increase_location_index == len(increasing_locations):
            merged_result.append(decreasing_locations[decrease_location_index])
            decrease_location_index += 1
        elif decreasing_locations[decrease_location_index] < increasing_locations[increase_location_index]:
            merged_result.append(decreasing_locations[decrease_location_index])
            decrease_location_index += 1
        else:
            merged_result.append(increasing_locations[increase_location_index])
            increase_location_index += 1

    return merged_result
```

Comment: Oh man, good call out. Unfortunately that just printed more bonkers results so I'm fudging something in my whole setup I think.

Comment: Does "run" mean every element is +/- from the one before it (i.e. +1, +1, +1 is fine; -1, +1, -1 is not)? If so, I can revise my answer.

Comment: Great question, I should definitely clarify. Yeah, so for instance the test with run_length of 3 would mean a run of 1, 2, 3 or a run of 3, 2 , 1 consecutively. This is pointing me a bit in a direction now because the last return on the test I ran was 10, which was 7, 8, 7 which should be ignored.

Comment: @kpbw I think I got it. You have to make a second pass through the list.

Comment: Interesting! I'm going to take some time to read over this and do my best to understand all the moving parts better as soon as I get time this afternoon, then follow up with some questions. I appreciate the time you've put into that!